# How to get an input to display and edit currency with angular 4 pipes

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe, angular2-ngmodel

My goal is to have an input field that allows the user to edit a number as currency.  E.g.  The user sees "$1,000", they can type a '0', and the edit box shows "$10,000".  And the resulting data model is a number 10000.

```
<input type="text" name="Data" [ngModel]="Data | currency:'USD':true:'4.0-0'" (ngModelChange)="Data=$event" >
```

The above displays in the edit box '$1,000', but when I edit the value in the input box, the value is no longer a number 1000, it is a string "$1,000".  Meaning my data model went from

```
{ myCost: 1000 }
```

to become

```
{ myCost: "$1,000" }
```

Any ideas on the correct way to do this?  It's looking like I need to create a new function to convert from currency back to number.  Which is possible, but it seems like there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle ngModelChange in your component class
`(ngModelChange)="onInputValueChange($event)"`

**In component.ts**
`onInputValueChange(newValue: any):Number {
 return <Number>newValue;
}`

Comment: Ya, looks like that is the only way.  Bummed because this means adding component logic.  And looks a little goofy because I want to extend this out to handle currency, dates, and all the other standard pipes.